# How to sample with the 1-norm?

Tags: sampling, regularization

I am currently working on ridge regression, which can be interpreted using Bayesian statistics (DOI: 10.1016/j.electacta.2015.03.123). In particular, I know that the maximum-a-posteriori (MAP) estimate can be computed with its uncertainty. However, is it possible to evaluate the MAP when the 1-norm is used instead of the 2-norm, i.e., for lasso regression? Moreover, how do you sample with the 1-norm?

Thank you in advance for your insights!